# Change Inet root folder for iis 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I am facing a very exasperating challenge. I have to deploy my ASP.NET MVC 3 application in a production server.

In this production server I have two drives **C:** and **D:**. I am authorized to put my websites in the **D:\data folder** and I cannot use the **C:**.

Unfortunately IIS creates the **Inet** directory in **C:** and apparently there is no way in the IIS manager to change this destination. Is there any way to change this directory? In the case this is not possible, is there any way to solve this problem in an alternative way?

Consider that I have my code stored in the **D:** of the production server and I have Visual Studio installed in it.

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the root folder of the website to whatever location you want. And if you create a virtual directory and host this MVC application inside the directory it could even be outside of the root of the web site:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately I'm new to deployment and it is giving me a bad headache. I heard about virtual directories but I do not know what is their use in this context...

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, what option did you select to bring up that dialog box?