# Sharepoint Web Applicantions Share Web.Config file

Tags: iis, sharepoint, web-applications, web-config

I have 2 sharepoint web app on the same port, with diferente iis sites, configured with Alternate Access Mappings, with distinct virtual directories.

The question is, the web.config file used on web app 1, is connected to Web App 2.

Changing the web.config file in virtual directory web app2 dont have any impact.
Changing the web.config file in virtual directory web app1 have direct impact on the 2 web apps.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The web.config is set based on where your root site is set. You can stop the site in IIS and specify the root folder for that site. How depends on which version of IIS you're using. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635657/change-inet-root-folder-for-iis-7) the instructions for IIS 7.