# Changing webroot in coldfusion doesn't serve static content from correct folder

Tags: coldfusion, webserver, iis-express

I updated my coldfusion 2023 developer edition on windows 11 pro webroot by editing server.xml to the following:

```
<Context path="/" docBase="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test-2-1" WorkDir="C:\ColdFusion2023\cfusion\runtime\conf\Catalina\localhost\tmp"  >
    <Resources>
      <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="C:\ColdFusion2023\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE" webAppMount="/CFIDE" />
      <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="C:\ColdFusion2023\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF" webAppMount="/WEB-INF" />
  </Resources>
</Context>
```

This works, coldfusion serves .cfm files from C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test-2-1

However, static content is not being served from the correct directory. Here's an example of the 404 error while trying to get a js file. I'm guessing I can update web.config to serve the files from the test-2-1 directory, but i'm not sure how.

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\js\jquery-3.6.0.min.js
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

Comment: You are using IIS? You don't need to change the CF config, just update the path in IIS for the site. It will take care of it all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635657/change-inet-root-folder-for-iis-7